# Taxonomy Parent Name

Tags: custom-taxonomy, templates

Was just wondering how I would modify this piece of code:

```
<?php
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
echo $term->parent;
?>
```

...to display the parent name, rather than just an integer? Currently it returns the ID.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
$parent = get_term_by( 'id', $term->parent, get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
if($parent):
    echo $parent->name;
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Works fine, tks!